# Triggering AWS AutoScaling Policies using non EC2-namespace metrics (custom triggers)

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

In the past, I have configured autoscaling groups with scale up & down policies that are triggered by standard cloudwatch alarms (using metrics like cpuutilization).

I am now configuring an auto-scaling policy for a new ASG that needs to use a custom trigger. For example, I wannt to trigger scaling based on the length of a job queue in a proprietary system.

I'm about to start looking into how to trigger this, and was wondering if and how others are triggering scale up / down policies other than using CloudWatch metrics from the EC2 namespace?

1 idea that I've had is to create an alarm based on an SNS topic (numberofmessagespublished > 0) and then publish to the topic. Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: Or an SQS-based alarm?